# How to divide integer by a constant integer with right shift operators?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm interested how to do this, because I just found out you can do integer multiplication easily, by using left shift operators:

```
x * 25 = (x << 4) + (x << 3) + x
```

Where the sum of base 2 powers equals to 25: 2^4+2^3+2^0 = 25

How does `x / 25` work out with right shifts?

Edit: I'm not going to replace division and multiplication in my programs by these shift operators in hope of speed boost ;)

Comment: You can look here for a start:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding This is common practice for fast integer math in assembly. At least it was some years ago, not sure if it is still in use.

Comment: you dont need to worry about optimization nowadays because compilers are say smarter. but just for the sake a `>>` is a floor(divide by two).

Comment: @Koushik, i know, i'm just interested in how it can be done.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, yes, i found this http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html - dont know why the duplicate posts got removed, they had good links

Comment: This answer gives a program that seems like a good shortcut to this complex calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6976383/1036205