# right shift a binary for division

Tags: c, bit, division

I learned that if you want to multiplicate any binary number with any binary number you do following:

1. you seperate the number which is the multiplicator in a binary number which holds only one 1. Example:

00000101 = 00000100, 00000001.

1. Then you do the leftshift which those new numbers
2. Then you simple add the results.

So what about division with any number?

I heard you do right shift, but that counts only for division by 2. But I want any number to divide. I am not talking about floating numbers. But how could I divide 25 / 5 in binary?

Please tell me an example, Thanks a lot!

I tried to do after the rightshift a subtraction (so in a way like the multiplication), but it won't work :(

**Example for multiplication for any numbers:**

00001111 * 00000101 means:

> 00001111 * 00000100 + 00001111 * 00000001
>    = 00111100 + 00001111 = 01001011 (result)

Comment: By shifting bits you can multiply/divide by only powers of 2. For any other multiplier/divisor, you'll have to do it in some other way. BTW, can you please give an example of the multiplication method you mentioned?

Comment: Have you seen these 

  [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850665/how-can-i-use-bit-shifting-to-replace-integer-division)
  [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776211/how-can-i-multiply-and-divide-using-only-bit-shifting-and-adding)
  [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088086/how-to-divide-integer-by-a-constant-integer-with-right-shift-operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for division.

The reason it works for multiplication is because [multiplication is distributive over addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)

```
17 * 5
17 * (4 + 1)
(17 * 4) + (17 * 1)
```

Division is not distributive

```
17 / 5
17 / (4 + 1)
(17 / 4) + (17 / 1) <== WRONG!!
```

Comment: would you be so kind and explain how divide 2 binary numbers? e.g. 1111:101 ? I trying to understand but i got just not simple explanation here... :(

Comment: @int80 just do it like normal decimal division

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way, only for powers of 2. But, there are certain methods possible for division by an integer other than a power of two. See [Hacker's delight - Integer division by constants](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf)
.