# Speeding up integer division with constant divisor

Tags: c++, c

I remember reading somewhere a while back that if you are dividing by a constant there is a way to turn it into a multiplication due to the properties of modular arithmetic.  I have been working on the following function and it involves performing many divisions with the same divisor.  I was wondering if I could speed it up using what I described above.  If so how exactly?

```
int ubi_div_i64(ubigint_t* a, ubi_i64_t b, ubi_i64_t* rem)
{
    if(b == 0)
        return UBI_MATH_ERR;

    ubi_i64_t r = 0;

    for(size_t i = a->used; i-- > 0;)
    {

        ubi_i64_t out;
        __asm__("\t"
                "div %[d] \n\t"
                : "=a"(out), "=d"(r)
                : "a"(a->data[i]), "d"(r), [d]"r"(b)
                : "cc");
        a->data[i] = out;
    }
    if(rem)
        *rem = r;

    return ubi_strip_leading_zeros(a);
}
```

Note:  The divisor is 64 bit and the dividend is 128 bit.

Comment: I think this might have the answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4891307/174614

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++. Also, if I recall correctly this trick is not going to be an improvement for this form of division as it needs a multiplication as large as the dividend.

Comment: What is the expected range of divident and divisor?

Comment: And state your assembly language.

Comment: The numerator will be a 64 bit type plus whatever the remainder of the last operation was.  So it needs to be 128 bit.  The divisor is 64 bit.

Comment: Before you try to optimize with hard to understand/maintain code, you should have a look at the assembler your compiler generates. You might be surprised how good modern compiler optimize your code. Note that this only works if you use a wider type for the multiplication, than for the division. This because it is effectively a fixed-point multiplication with  `1/dividend`. If you also need the remainder, it might very well take longer than a simple CPU-`DIV` instruction (depends on the architecture and CPU model, of course).

Comment: I guess it wont work because the only reason I am even using assembly right now is to support 128 bit division.

Comment: You only just touch on modular arithmetic. The accepted answer here might be relevant, with a special case where the modulus is a prime number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235110/modulo-of-division-oftwo-numbers

Comment: I share Olaf's opinion, but make sure you enable full optimisation. Please pick none of C or C++ because this question is actually about intel x86 assembly. The assembly just so happens to be embedded into C or C++ code using a gcc/clang extension (which this question is also not about).

Comment: Seb, I don't think that's true, it's about C or C++ and you can do it in a way that the C or C++ standard guarantees will work as long as you use a type like `uint32_t` or similar.

Comment: I guess he's indicating he wants to do it in assembly though.

Comment: Don't guess! OP, please tag your question correctly and specify your intent so we can give an accurate answer.

Comment: Olaf explains one way of doing this. You effectively do a fixed point multiplication where 1/a = 0.xxxxxxx . The problem is that you're dealing with a 128 bit dividend. If the divisor is small enough, then the quotient can  have more than 64 bits, in which case the fixed point multiply could require extended precision math.

Comment: I agree with Olaf etc. Are you sure that it is worthwhile optimising this part of the code. Perhaps better performance can be achieved elsewhere with less effort